# loops in my smart contract that I cant find

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I'm testing my contract and I got the following error:

Gas costs: Gas requirement of function vjkNFT.safeMint is infinite: If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed. Please avoid loops in your functions or actions that modify large areas of storage (this includes clearing or copying arrays in storage) Pos: 32:4:

Here the function that contains the error:

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract vjkNFT is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage, Pausable, Ownable, ERC721Burnable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

    uint256 public mintPrice = 0.05 ether;
    uint256 public maxSupply = 9999;
    mapping(address => uint) public mintedWallets;

    constructor() payable ERC721("vjkNFT", "VJK") { }

    function pause() public onlyOwner {
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() public onlyOwner {
        _unpause();
    }

    function setMaxSupply(uint256 _maxSupply) external onlyOwner{
        maxSupply = _maxSupply;
    }

    function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
        payable(owner()).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    function safeMint(string memory uri) external payable {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();

        require(mintedWallets[msg.sender] < 10, "exceeds max per wallet");
        require(msg.value == mintPrice, "wrong value");
        require(maxSupply > tokenId, "sold out");

        mintedWallets[msg.sender]++;
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();

        _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, string(abi.encodePacked("data:application/json;base64,", uri)));
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
        internal
        whenNotPaused
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
}
```

Someone know what this is about? Thank you

Comment: What does _safeMint do? Is it the one defined by openzeppelin?

Comment: Also: What about _tokenIdCounter.increment() and _tokenIdCounter.current() ? Can you provide those functions? The loop is hidden somewhere, but it's not in the code provided.

Comment: @Uriel Chami exactly... the _tokenIdCounter.increment() and _tokenIdCounter.current() are from openzeppelin.. good to know.. the loop is some where.. I will find :D thank you.. I forgot about openzeppelin in this case hehehe

Comment: Can you provide the whole .sol file so I can try it on my own environment?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean with whole.sol? I have a one file contract, that generated from Remix.org, that I used to test verify in etherscan.

Comment: The whole contract. Can upload here your code for the nft contract? I want to reproduce to find the loop myself

Comment: Running on remix I cannot reproduce the bug. I can execute safeMint succesfully. Any particular value of string uri that I should provide?

Comment: No, I just use any random string to test, like jjjjjjj, but also tested with the real Svg String. That's my question, here everything also run perfectly., but Remix still give me some erros, I'm afraid to deploy at main net.. I'll keep testing and studing.. Thank you so much for your time.. I really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, now I understand.

This is a duplicate of: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41851/solidity-function-gas-requirement-is-infinite

> You can safely ignore this warning. The problem is your string
> variable in the parameters `string uri`. Because a string has no fixed
> size, it is theoretically possible to require an infinite amount of
> gas to fill it with an infinite amount of characters.
>
> Your code will still compile and work if no other errors are being
> shown.

Comment: awesome @UrielChami. I thought about it, actually I think I saw this post at some point. But I was afraid to Deploy at MainNet with those errors. But it looks really fine. Thank you